# How do I do spaces for a path in a terminal command?

Tags: xcode, swift, unix, applescript

**SOLVED**

I needed to add two extra "\" so this line looks like this:

```
  let finalString = removeExtension.stringByReplacingOccurrencesOfString(" ", withString: "\\\\ ")
```

I have an app written in swift which runs a terminal command (unix) that opens and closes an app.

When the app selected is one word like "notes.app", the application works perfectly fine, however whenever it's an app with two words like "App Store.app", my program doesn't seem to be executing the commands correctly.

So, this works:

```
 clientUsed = "notes"
 let killCommand = "do shell script \"killall \(clientUsed)\""
 let openCommand = "do shell script \"open --hide --background /Applications/\(clientUsed).app\""
```

but this doesn't:

```
 clientUsed = "App\ Store"
 let killCommand = "do shell script \"killall \(clientUsed)\""
 let openCommand = "do shell script \"open --hide --background /Applications/\(clientUsed).app\""
```

**Does anyone with unix, applescript or swift experience know why this is happening? I don't know if it's taking the wrong data in because i've written the script wrong.**

For extra info if it helps, the variable clientUsed is determined by a `NSOpenPanel()` URL. Here is that code:

```
selectedApp = openPanel.URL!
var lastComponent = selectedApp?.lastPathComponent
var removeOptional : String = lastComponent!
let removeExtension = removeOptional.stringByReplacingOccurrencesOfString(".app", withString: "")
let finalString = removeExtension.stringByReplacingOccurrencesOfString(" ", withString: "\\ ")
self.clientUsed = finalString
```

Answer (score 0):

You don't need to delimit spaces inside a quote (as a string).

```
clientUsed = "App Store"
let killCommand = "do shell script \"killall \(clientUsed)\""
let openCommand = "do shell script \"open --hide --background /Applications/\(clientUsed).app\""
```

Answer (score 0):

Why in the world are you running `killall` via shell via AppleScript via Swift? Just use `[NSTask launchedTaskWithLaunchPath:arguments:]` to execute it directly. [1]

As for launching other applications, use `-[NSWorkspace launchApplication:]` or `-[NSWorkspace launchApplicationAtURL:options:configuration:error:]`.

--

[1] Be aware that on OS X you should only use `kill`/`killall` to terminate non-GUI or hung processes. The correct way to end a normally working GUI process is to send it a `quit` Apple event. Annoyingly, doing this directly from ObjC/Swift is a bit of a PITA these days due to `NSAppleEventDescriptor`'s [lack of a send method](http://openradar.appspot.com/19169736). You could use the `AESendMessage` function, but that's a legacy Carbon C API, so it may be simpler and safer to [use `NSAppleScript`](http://appscript.sourceforge.net/nsapplescript.html) or just bridge directly into AppleScript via AppleScript-ObjC, which is easy to do [from ObjC](http://appscript.sourceforge.net/asoc.html) and also doable (if a bit more work) [from Swift](http://macscripter.net/viewtopic.php?pid=175562#p175562).

Comment: I'm new to swift / programming in general so I wasn't sure of another way to do it. I'll look into what you suggested. Thanks for all the info!

Comment: I am trying to figure out the best way to quit and launch an application specified by a URL in swift.